# Canvas issue in Salesforce VF page

Tags: canvas, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I had developed an app using Canvas. While loading Canvas, it shows an error like,

Oops, there was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application [My app].Your browsing session has ended or is invalid. Please re-login to Salesforce.com again.

The app was working fine before. But now it is frequently showing this error. Also it teminates the salesforce session

The Access Method in the Canvas App Settings is Signed Request (POST)

Can anyone help me with that?

I searched in lot of forums many people faced it but didn't have any solution posted.